# Convert to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How do you convert this to Swift 3? I tried but I keep getting errors for animation .fromValue and animation.toValue (it's only those 2 lines i need)

```
extension UIView {

    func shake() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.07
        animation.repeatCount = 3
        animation.autoreverses = true

        // This line produces error
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.center.x - 10, self.center.y))
        // And this line produces error
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.center.x + 10, self.center.y))

        self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. It took some time to let the compiler not complain, but here's your first line, correctly done:

```
animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 10, y: self.center.y))
```

I'm saying "wow" because compared to your Swift 2 line:

```
animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.center.x - 10, self.center.y))
```

You are basically stuck between *two* things between Swift 2 and Swift 3:

- CGPointMake is now simply CGPoint. This is very minor, and I'd think you'd have found it.
- NSValue uses the Swift 3 syntax of `cgPoint`, but then *defining the point means using `CGPoint`.

This builds. But only after a few tries, and letting Xcode complain. I'm amazed that the upgrade to current syntax didn't catch this - but maybe because there were two issues to upgrade.

You can use it for your second build error. If that's all that's wrong - syntax - then I believe you are good to go.

Comment: Very often the upgrade doesn't catch those kind of init changes.  I've noticed it almost never catches things like CGRectMake to CGRect and CGVectorMake to CGVector

Comment: Yes, but it was the *combination* that threw me - NSValue requiring "cgPoint" and CGRectMake requiring "CGRect". Sure, nothing major once you see it - but the combination? (BTW, I agree about the upgrade not catching CGRectMake versus CGRect. No upgrade tool is perfect.)

Comment: I tried that before but i still get arrows for those 2 lines. (I'm using playgrounds)

Comment: Never mind, it started working now. Thanks